# Getting Error in publishing a C# winform app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[When I go to Project Properties/Publish tab this error is being  shown I have searched it alot but nothing valuable is found, Thanks in Advance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJU0B.png)

Comment: Saying this in Error : An error occurred trying to load the page.
cc4014f5-b18d-439c-9352-f99d984cca85

Comment: Repair or reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes I am updating its components

Comment: Make sure when reinstalling that you have the feature "ClickOnce Publishing Tools" checked under "Windows and Web Development".

Answer (score 0):

Updating Visual Studio should work, if not then Reinstalling Visual Studio will be required.

Windows 7: Go to Add and Remove Programs, find Visual Studio Installer (+year)
and choose 'change'. Once the window opens, click 'modify'
The default update options should be fine, simply click 'Modify'/'update' in the bottom right corner. Your project should be able to open the publish page after it finishes.